# Why angular is not finding the json file?

Tags: angular

I am trying to get a json array through a data.json file, but angular js does not find data.json (`returning 404 Error`). I have tried many ways but still unable resolve this issue (I just started to learn angular 2). Following is my related files and code:

```
app/user/user.service.ts // User Service File

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class UserService{
    private JsonDirectory: string = "app/data.json"
    constructor(private _httpReference: Http){}
    getUsers(){
        return this._httpReference.get(this.JsonDirectory)
                .map((responseReference:Response) => responseReference.json());
    }
}
```

In the same location I have another file named `user.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from './user.service';

export class UserComponent implements OnInit{
    UserArray = [];

    ngOnInit(){
        this.userService.getUsers()
            .subscribe(resUserData => this.UserArray = resUserData);
    }

}
```

Data.json File Code

```
[
    {"id":1,"name":"Ayaz","gender":"Male"},
    {"id":2,"name":"Ali","gender":"Male"},
    {"id":3,"name":"Shah","gender":"Male"},
    {"id":4,"name":"Khan","gender":"Male"}
]
```

I put the `data.json` file in different location like app/data.json, user/data.json and on root and then I changed the url according to the location, but it does not find it and returns `404 Error`.

Comment: keep it in assets & Then use `this.http.get('assets/file.json')`;

Comment: @ParthGhiya Thank you so much,I followed the instruction and it works +1

Comment: i updated as answer :) you can accept & +1 . Also Angular JS Is angular 1 And angular 2/4 onwards is angular. Use naming accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it in assets Folder & Use

```
this.http.get('assets/file.json')
```